# cannot load ggvis library

Tags: r, ggvis

installation went through with out problems but when I load the library I get the following:

```
library(ggvis)
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :  
there is no package called ‘httpuv’
```

Any advice?
Thanks, 
Fernando

Comment: Do you have package `httpuv`? I'm guessing you don't. Install `ggvis` again and check the log for any error message. I'm guessing something went wrong and you somehow didn't get the dependency `httpuv`.

Comment: If you just downloaded ggvis only from CRAN, you may not have all packages needed for `ggvis`. You probably want to do `install.packages("ggvis")`

Comment: Yes! httpuv was missing. Thanks for the quick response. (how do I give a check to your comment?)

Comment: @Fernando Who did you refer to?

Comment: It was  @Vlo's post what provide the answer

Answer (score 3):

With windows machine and R version 3.1.0 `install.packages("ggvis")` install all dependencies, including the package `httpuv`. The binaries for this package is in the CRAN repository.

As a suggestion try `install.packages("httpuv", repos = "http://cran.rstudio.com")` and see if it gives you errors.